# Is there a way to bring a Trello card back automatically from the archive on a due date?

Tags: trello, trello-cards, reminder

Probably not with Trello, but maybe with some integration.

What I need is a solution for archiving cards because I'm not going to work with them now, but later they would come back, so I would remember doing what should be done.

Something in the lines of some email "follow up" services out there that help you remind things and at the same time keep your inbox clean.

Answer (score 2):

It rather seems to be about how you organize your boards and lists.

- Technically, I have not seen such "popup from archive on due date" feature for tow years of extensive use of Trello.
- Logically, if you need to review or do anything with a card, then it is active and should be moved to a dedicated long-term list or board instead of archiving.

However, you have options:

1. If you know the date when you will review a card, set that as **Due Date** and move card to specific 'parked' list or board out of daily focus. Cards with due date will notify all subscribed members.
2. If you do not know the next review date, use the option to reply to card via email (it depends on your business logic, there are many ways to "tickle" cards) + Aging Power-up: when a card gets aged, you clearly see it's been idle for at least 2-4 weeks; when a followup service emails to a card and creates a comment, the card changes visually. Depending on email template, you can even mention members in comments, which triggers notifications. Also, consider moving cards to a dedicated list or board instead of archiving, so as to keep inbox clean (of course, do this only for the cards, which you have to review later; when a card is done, archive it the standard way).

Comment: "If you know the date when you will review a card, set that as Due Date and move card to specific 'parked' list or board out of daily focus. Cards with due date will notify all subscribed members." Really? All members subscribed to that list, you mean? That's a good way to do it.

Comment: Yes. When due date comes the Trello card notifies all subscribed members. Also, if you want to know about upcoming cards for you team switch to the calendar view (free power-up) and filter by members.

Answer (score 1):

Activate the "Card Snooze" power-up in your board.  From the description:

> Now you can clean up the clutter of cards you're not going to get to until another day. The Card Snooze Power-Up lets you to snooze a card until a later date and time, when it magically reappears on the board. Need it sooner? Find your card in "archived" cards.

I just discovered today that power-ups are available even on the free accounts. (It's been a while since I've visited Trello.)